# Redisco ListField unicode save error but validate true

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, redis, redis-py

```
class Article(models.Model):
       title = models.Attribute()
       tags = models.ListField(unicode)

 new = Article(title='what ever')
 new.tags = [ u'Niña', u'Niñb' ]

 new.is_validate()
 >>> True

 new.save()
```

While when load：

```
Article.objects.all()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In redis-cli:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> GET "Article:tags:5omv5reh"
(error) ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

So what's the reason that caused this?

Comment: As the error says: your saved Unicode data can't be displayed when decoded to ASCII.

Comment: @Simeon Visser so how to understand the redis-cli displayed? I think it was not saved successful.

Answer (score 1):

So after trying, the unicode string should always be encode and saved as string. When get, always be decode. here comes the code:

```
class Article(models.Model):
       title = models.Attribute()
       tags = models.ListField(str)

 new = Article(title='what ever')
 new.tags = [ u'Niña'.encode('utf-8'), u'Niñb'.encode('utf-8') ]

 new.is_validate()
 >>> True

 new.save()
```

When print:

```
 articles = Article.objects.all()
 for i in articles:
     print i.decode('utf-8')
```